# After Effects - Export Settings Window

Tags: after-effects

The Export Settings Window does not appear when I am trying to export a project to Media Encoder. ANy solution?

Comment: What version of After Effects are you using?  Was it showing up before?  Are you able to adjust settings in Media Encoder?  Why do you expect an export settings window?  I don't have CC, but looking at a video showing the functionality, there is no export settings window, all the settings that are available are set in the Media Encoder itself.

Comment: It was shwoing before . It is CC the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the quality settings, when exporting through Media Encoder, it appears that Adobe has dropped support for altering your render quality from After Effects.  You are only given options about the compression itself, presumably the high quality render settings are always used now since you can no longer specify them at all under the "new, improved" Adobe CC.

Comment: I want the export sound/audio thing

Comment: @user5635 can you help us out and maybe find a screenshot of what window you're referring to? I'm not exactly 100% what you mean by "sound/audio thing".

Comment: Fixed it . I just restored factory settings

Comment: @user5635 - out of curiosity, could you post a screen shot of the screen you intended.  We might be able to post a simpler method for others experiencing your problem.  Thanks.